# Отправка файла с помощью Formdata в React на сервер Express на NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

**На странице имеется форма и кнопка для отправки файла (используется React):**

```
const Upload = () => {
const [file, setFile] = useState();

const UploadContent = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target.files[0]) {
        setFile(event.target.files[0]);
    }
};

const OnSumbit = (event) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('customFile', file);

    axios.post(
        "http://localhost:3000/upload",
        formData,
        {
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
            },
        }
    )
        .then(res => {
            console.log(`Success` + res.data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
}

return <div>
    <h1 style={style}>Зона тестов</h1>
    <input
        accept="video/mp4"
        id="contained-button-content"
        multiple
        type="file"
        onChange={UploadContent}
    />
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={OnSumbit}>
        Сохранить и закрыть
    </Button>
</div>
```

}

**На сервере используется files-uploader:**

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  let sampleFile;
  let uploadPath;

  if (!req.file || Object.keys(req.file).length === 0) {
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
  }

  sampleFile = req.file.customFile;
  uploadPath = __dirname + '/uploads/' + sampleFile.name;

  customFile.mv(uploadPath, function(err) {
    if (err)
      return res.status(500).send(err);

    res.send('File uploaded!');
  });
});
```

**Ответ сервера:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Не могу разобраться в чём дело, почему не загружается файл. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.**

Answer (score 0):

Вместо того чтобы пытаться сохранить файл в стейт, лучше вставить input в форму и из неё уже создавать FormData:

```js
const Upload = () => {
  const OnSumbit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(event.target.form);

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3000/upload", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(`Success` + res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={OnSumbit}>
      <h1 style={style}>Зона тестов</h1>
      <input
        accept="video/mp4"
        id="contained-button-content"
        name="customFile"
        type="file"
      />
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Сохранить и закрыть
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Я убрал из файла атрибут `multiple`, поскольку в оригинальном коде всё равно попытки отправить один фапйл, но можно вернуть обратно - от этого работать клиентская часть не перестанет.

Я так же убрал `onClick` у кнопки. Если это настоящая кнопка, то она запустит процесс отправки формы по-умолчанию.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, но проблема была не в этом.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в элементарном отсутствии папок для сохранения файлов.

Для загрузки файлов использовался multer и сам скрипт модуль загрузки выглядит так:

```
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs');

const filePath = {
    common : './content/',
    imageFile: './uploads/images/',
    contentFile: './uploads/content/'
}

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, path.join(__dirname, '.' + filePath[file.fieldname]))
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        let name = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
        name = name.replace(':','-');
        let result = name + '-' + file.originalname;
        cb(null, (result))
    }
})

exports.Remove = function (path) {
    try {
        fs.unlinkSync(path);
        console.log('successfully deleted' + path);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

exports.upload = multer({storage: storage}).any();
exports.filePath = filePath;
```

Я объявил пути сохранения файлов, но не дал инструкцию по созданию папок, если они отсутствуют согласно кода:

```
common : './content/',
imageFile: './uploads/images/',
contentFile: './uploads/content/'
```

Таким образом, не найдя путь сохранения, программа пожимала плечами и продолжала жить своей жизнью, не видя в этом особой трагедии. Изменения в коде пока не делал, просто добавил папки по нужному пути. Однако, планирую добавить обработчик, чтобы они создавались автоматически при отсутствии.